# How can i get Output String Array All Possibility With Combination?

Tags: c#, combinations

I need to any String List output all possibility. Like that.
That is getting me 720 diffrent string.

```
List<String> items = new List<String>();
        items.AddRange(new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" });
```

> Output;
>
> 1-)  a b c d e f
>
> 2-)  a b c d f e
>
> 3-)  a b c e d f
>
> 4-)  a b c e f d
>
> 5-)  a b c f d e
>
> 6-)  a b c f e d
>
> 7-)  a b d c e f
>
> 8-)  a b d c f e
>
> 9-)  a b d e c f
>
> 10-) a b d e f c
>
> 11-) ...........
>
> 12-) ...........
>
> 13-) b a c d e f
>
> 720-)..........

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: bsouiler thank you I am try now that.

Comment: How do you know it gives you `720` different strings?

Comment: @S.Akbari Because 6! = 720

Comment: First char has 6 availables positions. Second char has 5 available positions, third char has 4 positions and so on... : 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 720.

Comment: @MatthewWatson And what about *Permutations with repetition*?

Comment: @S.Akbari OP's spec is talking about permutations. Doesn't mention duplicates in the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<String> items = new List<String>();
            items.AddRange(new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" });

            int i = 0;

            foreach (var permutation in Permute(items))
                Console.WriteLine(++i + ": " + string.Join(" ", permutation));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permute<T>(IEnumerable<T> seq)
        {
            return
                from item in seq.Select((value, index) => new {value, index})
                from remainder in seq.Count() == 1 ? new[]{new T[0]} : Permute(allExcept(seq, item.index))
                select new[]{item.value}.Concat(remainder);
        }

        static IEnumerable<T> allExcept<T>(IEnumerable<T> seq, int indexToSkip)
        {
            return 
                from item in seq.Select((value, index) => new {value, index})
                where item.index != indexToSkip 
                select item.value;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have duplicate strings in the input and you want to eliminate duplicate permutations in the output, then use `DistinctBy()` ([originally written by Jon Skeet](http://nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.DistinctBy)) like so:

```
var uniquePerms = Permute(items).DistinctBy(p => string.Join(" ", p));
```

where `DistinctBy()` is an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        return source.DistinctBy(keySelector, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        return distinctByImpl(source, keySelector, comparer);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TSource> distinctByImpl<TSource, TKey>(
        IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
        return source.Where(element => knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx worked, Is it that you wrote?

Comment: @MuratcanOguzhan I wrote the permutation code, but the enumerable extension method was originally by Jon Skeet, I think, as part of his MoreLinq project: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.DistinctBy/

Comment: Thank you @MatthewWatson , I am so grateful.

Comment: @MuratcanOguzhan FYI: I simplified the code with my last edit.

Comment: yes, last edit looks simpler. Again thanx. I changed methods.

Comment: Hello again, this code getting outpu 6!. You know that 6!/2 or 6!/3 . This mean 6!/3! = 6*5*4*3*2*1/3*2*1. If you know that please help me. Have a nice day.

Comment: @MuratcanOguzhan I'm not sure what you are after - if you have 6 different items, then the number of permutations is 6! (i.e. 720, which you mention in your OP). Can you clarify what you need? You might want to create a new question with the clarification too, since this one has been closed.

Comment: Yes this question closed, i had a new question. Example 6!=720 but optionally supposing I don't need 720 result only i need 6!/4!=30. This mean i have 6 diffrent caharacters but methods just need to bring 30 of them or 6!/3!=120.

Comment: Again Hello :D @MatthewWatson . Your method working excellent but i dont understand this method logic. How you can do this ? Please tell me this method business or logic :S.  If you want to tell please clearly express.I understand hardly.